# OpenVINO YOLOv4 inference device didn't appear after reboot with MYRIAD but could work with CPU

Tags: python, openvino, yolov4

My environment is Windows 11 with openvino_2021.4.752 version.

When I try to run *object_detection_demo.py* in the demos folder of inference engine, N/A result will be occurred using CPU, and the MYRIAD issue I will mention later will happened with my NCS2.

```
[ INFO ] Initializing Inference Engine...
[ INFO ] Loading network...
[ INFO ] Reading network from IR...
[ INFO ] Loading network to CPU plugin...
[ INFO ] Starting inference...
To close the application, press 'CTRL+C' here or switch to the output window and press ESC key
Latency: N/A
FPS: N/A
```

As a result, I try to run [TNTWEN/OpenVINO-YOLOV4](https://github.com/TNTWEN/OpenVINO-YOLOV4) on GitHub, and helpfully it works with CPU.

However, if I use MYRIAD as my inference device, the error `ncDeviceClose:1852      Device didn't appear after reboot` will happen with NCS2.

```
[ INFO ] Initializing Inference Engine...
[ INFO ] Loading network...
[ INFO ] Reading network from IR...
[ INFO ] Loading network to MYRIAD plugin...
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[0m
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[0m
[31mF: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherResponseServe:852       no request for this response: XLINK_WRITE_RESP 1
[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=433
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=433
[0m
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   [0m
Event sending failed[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92    [0m
Duplicate id detected.
[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=433
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[0m
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=433
[0m
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_READ_REL_REQ
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[0m
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   [31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Event sending failedDuplicate id detected.
[0m
[0m
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467  [0m

WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=433
[35mE: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] handleIncomingEvent:665  [0m
Assertion Failed: stream
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        [0m
Duplicate id detected.
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   [0m
Event sending failed[0m
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467  [0m

WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=433
[0m
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_CREATE_STREAM_REQ
[0m
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_READ_REL_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_CREATE_STREAM_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] checkGraphMonitorResponse:1934  Graph monitor request returned error 556750880[0m
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_READ_REL_REQ
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] ncFifoAllocate:3081     myriad NACK
[0m
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_RESP
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] checkGraphMonitorResponse:1934  Graph monitor request returned error 228373552[0m
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_READ_REL_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] checkGraphMonitorResponse:1934  Graph monitor request returned error 549973040[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_READ_REL_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.752\inference_engine\demos\object_detection_demo\python\object_detection_demo.py", line 361, in <module>
    sys.exit(main() or 0)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.752\inference_engine\demos\object_detection_demo\python\object_detection_demo.py", line 250, in main
    detector_pipeline = AsyncPipeline(ie, model, plugin_config,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.752\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\demos\common\python\pipelines\async_pipeline.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.exec_net = ie.load_network(network=self.model.net, device_name=device,
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 403, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IECore.load_network
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 442, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IECore.load_network
RuntimeError: Failed to create output FIFO: NC_ERROR
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_READ_REL_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] checkGraphMonitorResponse:1934  Graph monitor request returned error 549972400[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] checkGraphMonitorResponse:1934  Graph monitor request returned error 553885968[0m
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_READ_REL_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_CLOSE_STREAM_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_READ_REL_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_CLOSE_STREAM_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_RESET_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1132   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] ncDeviceClose:1852      Device didn't appear after reboot[0m
```

I think it is a bug with YOLOv4 using NCS2.

After all, I can use my CPU to do the YOLOv4 inference job successfully on this GitHub implementation with *object_detection_demo_yolov3_async.py* in the 2021.3 pythondemo folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue (running YOLOv4 model with Object Detection Python Demo on MYRIAD device) is a known bug in OpenVINO 2021.4.752. Our developers are fixing it.
On the other hand, I’ve validated the YOLOv4 model using Object Detection C++ Demo and it is working fine. For now, please use Object Detection C++ Demo as an alternative demo.